# How to change default structure of angular component creation

Tags: angular, typescript, vscode-extensions, angular-components

I want to add some default codes for all the components that I am going to create. I don't want to copy and paste same codes.

[image]

From the above image, I want to add those imports and injection part while the creation of a component itself.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Depending upon your use-case(s), you can make use of (m)any of various patterns while registering [providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers).

Comment: You need to write your own schematics on top of angular. Its not that difficult.